# Can calling Abort() on an IClientChannel proxy throw an exception?

Tags: wcf, proxy, wcf-client, abort

Based on documentation and articles it is recommended to call Abort() on a client proxy if an unexpected exception/fault is encountered. See the following (simplified):

```
MyServiceClient proxy = null;
try {
    proxy = new MyServiceClient();
    proxy.DoSomething();
    proxy.Close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (proxy != null)
        proxy.Abort();
}
```

Is there any possibility of the call to Abort() throwing an exception itself? Should the call to Abort() be within its own try/catch?

Comment: Why do you have a null check in this snippet?

Comment: I meant to put the instantiation of the proxy within the try block. Thus, the null check in case anything were to go wrong with the instantiation. Might be an overkill, but assures me I do have a proxy to Abort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Abort will not fail (but .Close() or .Dispose() might). Calling .Abort() is the "sledgehammer" approach to terminating a channel - it's just torn down, regardless of an ongoing message handling.

Use it only carefully - e.g. in a exception catch case when calling .Close() failed. That's it's real purpose and proper use.

Marc

Comment: What would happen if you didn't call abort on the channel in the above catch block?

Comment: The channel between the client and server wouldn't be properly closed and disposed of, so you would potentially have an unused channel lingering around in your system. Eventually, it'll be garbage-collected - but that take some time, and until then, it's using up system resources for no useful purpose.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up this claim?  I want to be sure that Abort will never throw any exceptions in any circumstances.

Comment: @ScottLerch: see the [MSDN documentation on ChannelFactory.Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.communicationobject.abort.aspx) - it doesn't list any possible exceptions that would be thrown